# Only apply hover effects after a certain amount of time, but also remove the effect if the mouse exits

Tags: javascript

Trying to set up a grid like page of divs that will fire a hover event over each div, but only if the mouse stays on the hover for a second or so.

I have a pen I'm working on here: https://codepen.io/skypod/pen/bOBZRQ?editors=0011

The specific section I'm working on is on lines 142 - 149 in the JS file.

That code is:

```
var t;
$('.pixel').hover(function(){    
  t = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('hovering');
  }, 2000); 
}, function(){
  clearTimeout(t);
});
```

I'd like it function like so. You move the mouse over the page and nothing logs to the console. You stop moving the mouse for a couple seconds, and the timeout finishes and fires the hover function ONCE.

Right now it does that, but it fires EVERY hover function for every div you've hovered over in the duration of the timeout. For example, you hover over divs 1, 2, and 3 over the 2000ms of the timeout, and it fires the hover function for all 3 divs. I want it immediately clear the hover function on the divs you are no longer hovering over. I feel like I'm close, but I'm missing something simple.

Comment: `clearTimeout(t)` only clears the most recent timeout `t`. By constantly updating it to hold a new timer, you lose the ability to clear previous timers. [An example](https://jsfiddle.net/3eo7z9rd/)

Comment: Add `clearTimeout(t)` before `setTimeout`, to get rid of the old timer if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! Tyler Roper - That's good advice. And thank you @Barmar - adding it again before setting a new timeout solved the problem! I knew it was something minor that I was missing.